# Java and Which Stun libraries i should use?

Tags: java, stun

Java, i was trying to write my own STUN client, but it seems like i was making mistake and therefore, most of the time it gets freezed. So i would like to know what STUN Client libraries are available for Java, to get started.

Follow up: (in the mean time trying following, still involved no solution for behind NAT/firewall)

Step 1: Stun class: http://babbly.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/org/babbly/core/net/InetAddresResolver.java

```
/* modified */
import java.io.*;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import net.java.stun4j.StunAddress;
import net.java.stun4j.client.SimpleAddressDetector;
import java.util.Random;

public class stun
{

  public static final int    MAX_PORT_NUMBER = 65535;
  public static final int    MIN_PORT_NUMBER = 1024;
  private static DatagramSocket socket = null;
  private static SimpleAddressDetector detector;

    public static synchronized InetAddress resolveInternetInterface(InetAddress dest)
    {

        InetAddress networkInterface = null;

        if(dest == null)
        {
            try {
                dest = InetAddress.getByName("78.12.2.61");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            }
        }

        if(dest != null)
        {
            socket.connect(dest, getRandomPortNumber());
            networkInterface = socket.getLocalAddress();
            socket.disconnect();    
        }

        if(networkInterface == null || networkInterface.isAnyLocalAddress())
        {
            try{
                networkInterface = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
            }
        }
        return networkInterface;
    }

    public static synchronized InetAddress resolveInternetInterface()
    {
        return resolveInternetInterface(null);
    }

    public static int getRandomPortNumber()
    {
        return new Random().nextInt(MAX_PORT_NUMBER - MIN_PORT_NUMBER);
    }

  public static InetSocketAddress getPublicAddress(int localPort)
  {
    InetSocketAddress resolvedAddr = null;
    String stunAddressStr = "stun.xten.com";
    String portStr = "3478";
    int stunPort = Integer.parseInt(portStr);

    StunAddress stunAddr = new StunAddress(stunAddressStr, stunPort);
    detector = new SimpleAddressDetector(stunAddr);

    System.out.println("Created a STUN Address detector for the following " + "STUN server: " + stunAddressStr + ":" + stunPort);

    detector.start();
    System.out.println("STUN server detector started;");

    StunAddress mappedAddress = null;
    try {
      mappedAddress = detector.getMappingFor(localPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("lala");
    detector.shutDown();
    if(mappedAddress != null)
    {
      System.out.println("stun: no nat detected");
      resolvedAddr = mappedAddress.getSocketAddress();

    } else {

      System.out.println("sun: nat detected, hitting the ip");
      String dstProperty = "78.22.22.61"; // put the ip of the target to hit
      InetAddress destination = null;
      try {
        destination = InetAddress.getByName(dstProperty);
      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      InetAddress publicHost = resolveInternetInterface(destination);
      resolvedAddr = new InetSocketAddress(publicHost, localPort);

    }

    return resolvedAddr;

  }
```

Step 2: Using it

```
InetSocketAddress test;
test = stun.getPublicAddress(40446);
System.out.println("STUN: " + test.toString());
```

Step 3: Result

```
Created a STUN Address detector for the following STUN server: stun.xten.com:3478
STUN server detector started;
Apr 18, 2011 7:04:16 PM net.java.stun4j.stack.NetAccessPoint start
INFO: Bound a socket on ap: net.java.stun4j.stack.AccessPoint@0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:40446 status:  running
Apr 18, 2011 7:04:17 PM net.java.stun4j.stack.NetAccessPoint stop
INFO: Closed socket on ap net.java.stun4j.stack.AccessPoint@0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:40446 status:  running
lala
stun: no nat detected
STUN: /78.12.2.61:40446
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is

- JSTUN: http://jstun.javawi.de/
- STUN: http://java.net/projects/stun

See also: [STUN, TURN, ICE library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039147/stun-turn-ice-library-for-java)

Comment: This one has a built in JAR and Example. You mention few links, but those works or without JAR file, do they have any static modules or most of them built in SERVER instead of simple Client method? ex: http://code.google.com/p/babbly/source/browse/trunk/src/org/babbly/core/net/InetAddresResolver.java

Comment: 1st one does not have any example or docs. Second one is almost a mess collection. Third link no accurate answer.

Comment: Anything in a JAR file? Just a small, above i prepared one, but still its too much to code.

Comment: JSTUN is in a Jar file, contains client and server. If you download the source, there is documentation inside, in the form of demo's and unit tests.

Comment: Are you writing a STUN client or a STUN server? With JSTUN you can test both server and client. With that you can fix your own implementation.