# Simulating Calls in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

everyone!
I've encountered an interesting challenge while testing a messenger. I'm using JMeter to record traffic (login, call, and conversation). When running the script, the call lasts only 14 seconds and automatically terminates before the "end call" request.
The call request includes ICE config with STUN and TURN, as well as candidates.
In the future, I plan to create a script for connecting to a group conference to check its capacity.
Question: How can I (if possible) simulate this call in JMeter? Perhaps someone has faced a similar situation and can share their experience or suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it evidenced by its name JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder can only record HTTP or HTTPS traffic.

It won't record any [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) calls. You will need to capture them somehow, i.e. using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and then look for suitable JMeter Plugins like [WebSocket Sampler](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/) or Java libraries supporting [STUN/TURN/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469398/simple-stun-client-in-java)WebRTC protocols and use them from [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)