# Transmitting to a host on another subnet

Tags: networking, ip

I have two small questions:

1. When a packet needs to be transmitted to a host on another subnet,
   what IP address will be used in the destination field of the IP
   header?
2. When a packet needs to be transmitted to a host on another subnet,
   what IP address will be used in the destiantion field of the MAC
   header?

Answer (score 1):

The key point is:

For normal routing, dest ip src ip stay the same, while dest mac "or" src mac changes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send to the gateway of the other subnet, which, in turn, needs to have configured proper routing so that it will send it to the subnet host. Assuming they are on different networks as you said, there isn't a direct MAC address association, so you must send it to the gateway and both headers would refer to the gateway's address.

[This may be of interest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601570/how-to-send-packets-between-two-ip-hosts-on-different-subnets)